# extending a module when module is using "module.exports"

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, extending

I've read a few pages on extending a module.They revolve around using a functional form of a module and I get how to do it  (from https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/)

```
var Module = (function () {

  return {
    publicMethod: function () {
      // code
    }
  };

})();
```

but what I have is two modules like this

`util.js`

```
module.exports = {
    thing1: function() {// do thing1 stuff }      
}
```

`extend.js`  a package I can't change (from npm)

```
module.exports = {
    thing2: function() {// do thing2 one stuff}
}
```

now pretending I am going to use my util.js module

```
const _ = require('util.js);

let catin = _.thing1;  // that's easy
let thehat = _.thing2;.  // this was util.js extended.
```

I could in `util.js` just do this.

```
const ex = require('extend.js')

module.exports = {
    thing1: function() {// do thing1 stuff }
    thing2: ex.thing2
}
```

and that's ok since extend.js only has one function/method to extend, but I would like to extend this into my util library  https://github.com/dodekeract/bitwise/blob/master/index.js but it has 22! items to extend.

There must be a better slicker way yes?

I'm open to refactoring my util.js file (but not hand coding each extension like I showed) so it extends automatically but obviously can't refactor that package I'm not maintaining, short of a fork...ugh.  Also not interested in adding a sub deal like

```
  ex: ex 

_.ex.thing2
```

Ideas?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/171251/3284355 to see how to merge 2 objects.

Comment: sometimes you get into a mental corner and can't see the simple answer.  Of course I have merged objects before but I was so focused on "modules".  thx @Molda.  If you need rep then make a post I can upvote and choose as my answer.

Comment: Don't worry about *rep*, i'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given Molda's hint I'll share what I put together to make this question more useful for others.  I put together a simple way of building a (utility) module from a folder of (utility) modules plus other one off packages (e.g. bitwise)

Make a `utils.js` module in say `lib/`  with this (you'll need require-all or some such package)

```
let utils = require('require-all')(__dirname + '/util');
let bw = require('bitwise');

let self = module.exports = (function(){
let util={};
for (var key in utils) {
   util = utils.object.merge_keys(util,utils[key])
 }
 util = utils.object.merge_keys(util,bw)
 return util;
 }());
```

now make a subdirectory `lib/util/`  and fill it with your utility modules.  Have one of those modules contain this key/function

```
merge_keys: function (obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}
```

and be sure that module name matches the key used in this line `util = utils.object.merge_keys(util,utils[key])`. In my case I have a module `object.js` in `lib/util/` containing `merge_keys`

Then just require the utils.js module and all will be as one including access to the merge_keys function for other merging :-).

```
let _ = require('./lib/utils');
// see if it worked
console.log(_);
```

**beware:** there is no checking for duplicate key names between modules

**notes:**
`let self=` allows one to refer to any other key within the merged object itself like `self.myfunctionkeyname(  )`